# Работа с каталогами в Линукс

Tags: java

Работаю с каталогами и файлами в линуксе. Например у меня есть следующий кусок кода:

```
File f = new File("/media/yevhenii/Local disk D/Books");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

В результате выведеться полный путь, вроде "/media/yevhenii/Local disk D/Books". Как можно отделить первые два каталога(т.е. /media/yevhenii/) от стальной части? Я думал через substring(), но если у меня будет другой путь(например /media/yevhenii/Local disk D/Books/Books2) то substring() будет работать криво. Т.е. суть в том, чтоб для любой длины путей удалялись первые два каталога. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А если их всего 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не проверял под Linux, но должно работать:

Начиная с 1.7 в Java есть новое API для работы с файлами [`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html). Можно сделать следующее:

```
File f = new File("/home/user/somedir/somefile" );
Path p = f.toPath(); // переход на новое api
System.out.println( p ); // вывод: /home/user/somedir/somefile
// вернет путь p относительно /home/user
Path rel = Paths.get( "/home/user/" ).relativize( p ); 
System.out.println( rel ); // вывод: somedir/somefile

// вернет часть пути от третьего элемента до конца
Path subpath = p.subpath( 2, p.getNameCount() );
System.out.println( subpath ); // вывод: somedir/somefile
```

`Path` можно превратить обратно в `File` методом `path.toFile()`, но новые классы и методы принимают `Path`, например `java.nio.file.Files.copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)`, или `java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Path path): List<String>`.

Comment: А если, я допустим, вывожу дерево каталогов и мне нужно убрать все предыдущие каталоги из дерева? Например:
вместо вывода:
Local Disk D/Books
Local Disk D/Books/Books2

Мне нужно получить вывод в таком виде:
Local Disk D/
                    Books/
                              Books2/

Comment: `path.getFileName()` возвращает последний элемент пути. `path.getName(int index)` возвращает элемент пути по номеру, 0 - ближайший к корню.

Answer (score 0):

Решается проблема очень просто: с помощью `substring()`

Вроде:

```
  f.getAbsolutePath().substring(16)
```

Comment: А первые две директории всегда одинаковые?

Comment: Да. В линуксе да